# Why can't I connect to a dockerized service from my host?

Tags: docker, networking

I have this docker-compose.yml:

```
piousbox@Vadims-MacBook-Pro:~/projects/docker/mongo$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    image: 'mongo:4.0.1'
    command: mongod --port 27025 --bind_ip_all
    ports:
      - '27025:27025'
```

If I ssh into the container, I can do `mongo --port 27025` but from the host, I can't Why is that? I'm on a Mac 10.13.6, firewall disabled, pfctl is enabled but not blocking 27025.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! It's because the docker machine was installed in such a way that it has its own ip, and not localhost:

```
piousbox@Vadims-MacBook-Pro:~/projects/ruby/CreditNinjaAdmin$ docker-machine env default
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/piousbox/.docker/machine/machines/default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval $(docker-machine env default)
```